# How to increase line spacing in the title of moderncv

Tags: titles, moderncv

how can I increase line spacing in the title of moderncv?
My title contains double backslash:

```
\title{\color{blue}{Experienced Manager and Analyst \\in Banking \\and Financial Services}}
```

Comment: `\\[2cm]`   would be a bigger space (note `\color{blue}` does not take an argument, you should remove the `{` from before `Ex` and remove the close brace at the end.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks a lot!

This solution works for me:

`\title{\color{blue}\huge Experienced Manager and Analyst
\texorpdfstring{\\[0.1cm]in Banking}{}
\texorpdfstring{\\[0.1cm]and Financial Services}{}}`

Comment: I added


`\texorpdfstring{\\[0.1cm].......}{}` to remove a warning

Comment: I added `\huge` as well, just to make the title larger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In almost all places `\\`  is defined (normal text, `tabular`, `centering` ...) it has an optional argument giving a length for additional space so `\\[2cm]`